# CSZCMS Creating new Controllers and Views

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have just started codeigniter. Here I have different layout for the home page and inner page (eg about). So I created

$route['about'] = "About"; in routes.php and created controller called About in about.php. In the controller I have load view header, footer, content.

It displays the error in menu section where I created menu using default CSZCMS echo $this->Headfoot_html->topmenu($cur_page); It throws error in $cur_page. In home page this works fine since it is default controller creatng wen installing CSZCMS

Please guide me

Comment: unrelated, I just looked at the core code of CSZCMS out of interest... unimpressed. I also think its intended to be used without any coding.

Comment: Can u show me Controller and View?